# Upload data to BlobStore using remote api

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to upload blob to blobstore using remote API (not the standard upload scheme)?

I want to write backup/restore script for my application and blobstore is the only thing that doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest using Python MultipartPostHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blobstore access over Remote API was added three days ago:

> - Remote API now supports the Blobstore API. ([Changelog](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes))

---

> remote_api works at the lowest level
>   of the datastore, so once you've set
>   up the stub, you don't have to worry
>   about the fact that you're operating
>   on a remote datastore: With a few
>   caveats, it works exactly the same as
>   if you were accessing the datastore
>   directly. ([App Engine Help](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/articles/remote_api.html))

Comment: But there is no way to upload object to blobstore from the code.

Comment: I mean I can only read blobs from blobstore, and can't put them there.

Comment: I can't try it out, I have no access to the Blobstore.

Comment: Correct, just like you can't write to the blobstore in program code that's running on the production servers; all data going in to blobstore needs to be posted to a created upload URL.

Comment: You can use remote_api to get an upload URL from the blobstore, then post your file to it. That'll require a bit of custom code for an upload handler. We'd like to add support for this to remote_api, but it's not there quite yet.

Answer (score 1):

I once solved the problem of programmatically uploading to the blobstore and wrote a short tutorial/explanation for it on my blog. Hope it's useful: http://swizec.com/blog/programatically-uploading-to-blobstore-in-python/swizec/1423

Answer (score 0):

There's a better solution with the new files API: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html

This works well for me. Here is some sample code:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from google.appengine.api import files
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

def get_blob_key(self, data, _type):
    # Create the file
    file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type = _type)

    # Open the file and write to it
    with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write(data)

    # Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
    files.finalize(file_name)

    # Get the file's blob key
    blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
    return blob_key
```